# QtQuick 2 Pass function to elements

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick, qtquick2

I have a **QML element "Button"** which has a **MouseArea element inside**.
What I want to do is to **send a function to the item and then pass it to MouseArea**:

Example:

```
Button{
    id: smth
    ... 
    ...
   onClicked: console.log("Someone Clicked Me!")

}
```

And my element could be something like this:

```
Rectangle{
    property var onClicked
    ...
    MouseArea{
       onClicked : parent.onClicked
    }
}
```

I found out that I can pass the function like in native js without parentheses, but I think there is a way to implement it like MouseArea element does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way to handle this situation in QML is to let the Button **emit a signal**, which is then handled by the user of Button.

Button.qml:

```
Rectangle {
    id: root
    signal clicked

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: root.clicked();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Button {
    onClicked: console.log("Button was clicked!");
}
```